# Find SSO Server / Service solution like CAS but PHP/ASP.NET

Tags: single-sign-on, cas

I want to find a solution like CAS (www.jasig.org/cas) but source code is PHP or ASP.NET.

I have some websites, ex

- www.abc.com
- forum.abc.com
- support.abc.com
- *.abc.com

and

- www.xyz.com
- *.xyz.com

I want all user data (username, fullname, email, password_hash,...) are strored on 1 server (ex: id.abc.com / id.xyz.com). User just neeed login 1 place for access websites

I can not build a system like jasig CAS just want to find a solution like CAS made by PHP/ASP.NET.

Give me some idea.

Thanks !

Comment: Search Google for "PHP SSO" and then start digging through the search results.  Relevant open source projects show up around page 3 or 4, lots of SO questions and poorly written tutorials show up before that.

Comment: Wouldn't CAS work with PHP and .net as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reasons, we will build own SSO Service !

Thanks !